# How to create context menu or right click menu on button

Tags: eclipse-rcp

when i right click on button open a context menu. how i will do it. i try this code also

```java
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(btn.getText());

btn.getText().setMenu(menu);

getSite().registerContextMenu(menuManager, btn);

getSite().setSelectionProvider(btn);
```

I got problem in createContextMenu. Please Help me

Answer (score 2):

`createContextMenu` requires a `Control` as its argument, you are passing the button text `String`. The `setMenu` method also belongs to `Control`. So:

```java
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu(btn);

btn.setMenu(menu);

getSite().registerContextMenu(menuManager, btn);
```

`Button` does not implement `ISelectionProvider` so you will have to write one if you want to use the button as the selection provider.

Note that a part can only register one context menu like this and there can only be one selection provider for a part.

If you want context menu contributions from other parts of Eclipe to be added to the menu you must add the line:

```java
menuManager.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
```

Comment: we have to register context menu and set selection Provider also. without all this we cannot show menu manager

Comment: I did all changes which you suggest but I unable to view right click option on button

Comment: Well have you actually added anything to the menu anywhere?

Comment: Added note about getting 'standard' context menu items

Comment: menuManager.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));                              When I use this code then i want have to create a class of groupmaker and iworkbenchactionconstant also.

Comment: No, these are existing classes. `GroupMarker` is in the `org.eclipse.jface` plugin. `IWorkbenchActionConstants` is in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench`.